# Refresh Event not working on Firefox browser

Tags: angularjs, firefox, web-applications, angular-ui-router

I have an application built using angular js with angular ui router. Below is my application URL

```
http://localhost:8082/sample/#/test/1
```

On click of enter in the browser address bar, the page refresh happens in chrome,
but it doesn't work in firefox. But refresh works in firefox if there is any change in the URL. Browser refresh should work on enter even there is no change in the URL.

Anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The refresh on enter doesn't work because you use `#` in your url (anchors). Anchors has made to smooth scrolling page to appropriate element id on page. So, if you want it to refresh, try use `pushState` and urls without `#`.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated the "#" in the url tells the browser you are using anchor to scroll to and it prevents the refreshing of the page. Thats the default implementation in every browser including chrome. Angular uses the '#' to prevent browser reloading when changing between pages.

A solution for this can be utilizing HTML5 history API which will also  allow for your urls to be prettify and not include '#'. This is done by setting the $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in your config:

```
angular.module('sample', [])

.config(function($locationProvider) {
    //etc..
    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I refresh I am getting 404 error (I am using nested states)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox (for me, at least) refreshing leads to a `/` character being appended to the URL, which breaks the app.